# Extracting with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently working on a python program that extracts information from a stock website

http://markets.usatoday.com/custom/usatoday-com/html-mktscreener.asp

I need to extract all the columns Symbol - Volume. Before this program I had to create a bash scrip that downloaded the pages every minute for 1 hour to get 60 pages. Which I have done. But I do not understand how to extract the information so I can inject that information into MySQL db.

```
import libxml2
import sys
import os
import commands
import re
import sys

import MySQLdb

from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

# for converting dict to xml 
from cStringIO import StringIO
from xml.parsers import expat

def get_elms_for_atr_val(tag,atr,val):
   lst=[]
   elms = dom.getElementsByTagName(tag)
   # ............

   return lst

# get all text recursively to the bottom
def get_text(e):
   lst=[]
   # ............
   return lst
def extract_values(dm):
   lst = []
   l = get_elms_for_atr_val('table','class','most_actives')
   # ............
   #    get_text(e)
   # ............
   return lst
```

I'm very new to python and that's the best provided. There are 60 HTML pages downloaded and all I need to do is just extract the information from 1 page I believe Or at least if I can start on the 1 page I can figure out a loop for the others, and extract that information to be used in MYsql

Any help to get me started is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a robust HTML parser instead of `xml` module, as the latter will reject malformed documents, like the URL you pointed appears to be. Here's a quick solution:

```
from lxml.html import parse
import sys

def process(htmlpage):
    tree = parse(htmlpage).getroot()

    # Helper function
    xpath_to_column = lambda expr: [el.text for el in tree.xpath(expr)]

    symbol = xpath_to_column('//*[@id="idcquoteholder"]/table/tr/td[1]/a')
    price  = xpath_to_column('//*[@id="idcquoteholder"]/table/tr/td[3]')
    volume = xpath_to_column('//*[@id="idcquoteholder"]/table/tr/td[6]')

    return zip(symbol, price, volume)


def main():
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        with open(filename, 'r') as page:
            print process(page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You will have to elaborate on this example a bit, as some elements (like the "Symbol") are further contained in `span` or `a` nodes, but the spirit is: use XPath to query and extract column contents. Add columns as needed.

Hint: use Chrome Inspector or Firebug to get the right XPath.

EDIT: pass all the filenames on the command line to this script. If you need to process separately each file, then remove the `for` loop in `main()`.

Comment: Thing is instead of using the website I am using pages downloaded by a bash script I had to create that downloads the page and calls the python code. The Pages are labelled like this UsaToday-2013-05-16-00.html - UsaToday-2013-05-16-59.html